# Observing an event horizon while approaching one

Tags: gravity, black-holes, astronomy, time-dilation, event-horizon

A thought crossed my mind that I realized was hard to conceptualize so I decided to simplify the question by putting it in terms of event horizons.

If I am an observer approaching black hole "A", and I track another blackhole "B" in the distance, as I fall toward A's event horizon would blackhole B's event horizon appear to:

- grow
- shrink
- grow then shrink
- shrink then grow
- almost no change

And in choosing one, which factors would be affecting this observation? Some thoughts I was having was the issue of never seeing something fall into a black hole due to time dilation. As you got closer to A's event horizon more of the objects around B would appear to speed up so essentially at least the horizon would get..."sharper"? But then, everything is speeding up relative to you so time is passing much quicker at blackhole B and....

I dunno. My head starts getting in a twist when I start to parse out the different phenomena happening.

Any insights would probably help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Look, space arround a black hole is very much squeezed and time runs slower as compared to a far away point.
Light coming from B would then be squeezed and B's event horizon would shrink as you move closer to A. Also you would see the outside universe in speeding up motion.

Answer (score -1):

The opposite would actually happen. Time slows down as you get near any massive body. and at one point, time slows down too much that it almost pauses. what you will be seeing is that blackhole B is actually at rest.

Comment: Well the observer would fall at normal time speeds right? The universe to the observer would speed up. Anyone observing the observer falling toward blackhole A would see the observer slowing down right?